# Copy-pasting group of object with the same keyframe (Blender video editor)

Tags: video-sequence-editor, keyframes

I'm a beginner seeking wisdom to learn.

So this temporary 6 secs Youtube [video](https://youtu.be/RnjHOwNt9Ks) is to show what I've been trying and finally able to achieve. But the process is a hard-long painful way as shown in this screenshot:
[image: Blender screenshot]

Each of those small boxes is copy-pasted and then manually edited:

1. start frame
2. X-Y offset
3. keyframe in (opacity 1)
4. keyframe out (opacity 0)

It will take forever to finish just one video in this way. I'm pretty sure a more efficient way is out here somewhere. At least the last two processes (keyframes in & out) which all the same should be automated. Maybe Ctrl+C & Ctrl-V is not the way to do it? Educate me please...

Many thanks!

Comment: Instead of doing it manually, you may want to use a project like this: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/clockworx-music-nodes-some-issues-to-solve/11845/76